# Find which letters from the input match somewhere in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I have an array of strings. A user typed “ztaf”. How can I use JavaScript to find which of the letters the user typed match somewhere in the array? The answer should be “taf”.

```js
var array = [ "tofu", "fish", "meat" ];
var user_type = "ztaf";
var found = ""; // It should be "taf".
```

I have tried it, but it keeps saying there is no match.

Comment: "I have tried it but its keeps saying there is no match" please edit your question and show us what you have tried. For starters, your first line has unnecessary escape characters leading to syntax errors. `var array = ["tofu", "fish", "meat"];` is how it should be defined.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `join`?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones "*your first line has unnecessary escape characters*" I think that's because of the new question ask wizard that was introduced. I've seen other posts recently where characters are escaped in code where they shouldn't. Seems to be markdown and HTML characters like `[`, `]`, `*`, `_`, `<` and similar.

Comment: Why do you need to match against an Array? Wouldn’t a string like `"tofufishmeat"`, or even an alphabetized [Set](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) such as `new Set("aefhimostu")` (`new Set(array.join(""))`) be much easier to reason about? Then something like `Array.from(user_type).filter((char) => set.has(char)).join("")` would be trivial. What do you need this result for, anyway?

Comment: @Ross Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) along with the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) methods.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var array = ["tofu","fish","meat"];

var user_type = "ztaf";

var found = user_type.split('').filter(char => array.join().includes(char));

console.log(found.join(''));
```